# Import a workspace with pod in a other similar worskspace in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, workspace

I built 2 swift projects. Both use CocoaPod, so these projects are workspaces.

The first one is like a framework with a lot of Classes I use in the second one.
I don't succeed in this importation:

[image]

I followed those steps from the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_Project_to_a_Workspace.html) , but any Classes from my Framework (1st project) are recognized... I have 80 error like this :

> Use of undeclared type < MyFrameworkClass >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 5 Very easy solution in your POD File

```
in your directory :  touch Podfile (file will create in workspace)


# platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'TestWorkSpace'
xcodeproj 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'

    target 'Project1' do
        xcodeproj 'Project1/Project1.xcodeproj'
        #Pods for Project1
        pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
    end

    target 'Project2' do
        xcodeproj 'Project2/Project2.xcodeproj'
        #Pods for Project2
        pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

I know two options for setting up a workspace with multiple pods.

You can create a single podfile  for both projects. As you can imagine, it will create a single workspace where your two projects (app and framework) will be at (let's cocoapods take care of the entire workspace).

The pod file will look like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
workspace 'WorkspaceName’

xcodeproj ‘FolderOfApp/Project.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj ‘FolderOfApp/App.xcodeproj'

target :ApptTarget do
    xcodeproj 'FolderOfApp/App.xcodeproj'
    pod ‘MyAppPod’
end

target :FrameworkTarget do
    xcodeproj 'FolderOfFramework/Framework.xcodeproj
    pod ‘MyFrameworkPod’
end
```

You will probably need to add the "MyFrameworkPod" to the AppTarget too, and this bring some warnings that I still couldn't solve.

Anyway, you have another option that I was using before. Create and execute the two pod files as you are doing now, create another workspace, add the two projects and the two pods (separate them with folders). **DONT ADD THE WORKSPACES**, just the projects.

With this approach I had a feel problems like the app not finding the frameworks dependencies, but I solved adding the framework search path.